# Reliably get location of bundled executable on Linux

Tags: c#, directory, mono

I'm writing a C# application that's being compiled and bundled with Mono's `mkbundle`, and then run.

I'm attempting to access the folder that the executable is being run in, which works when I run the application from the directory that it's in, using `./example`. However, when running it relatively from another directory, such as `../Builds/example`, it returns the wrong directory, instead returning the place it was executed from.

This all works perfectly on Windows, however I also need it to work for Linux too.

The methods I've previously tried are:

- `AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory`
- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.ExecutingAssembly().Location)` (also tried `EntryAssembly`)

All of these return the incorrect directory, rather than the actual location of the executable.

Comment: This is a problem with Mono - their implementation of that API is perhaps iffy. ode. You may need to devise a workaround for Mono. But first of all, look at how exactly does the mkbundle's output look. E.g. whether it's a script that runs a temporary binary, etc. This may give you hints as to what the workaround may be. You'd also do well to look into Mono's sources to see if there's clearly a problem there. It may be a problem with the interaction of mkbundle with Mono's .NET implementation.

Comment: Per the duplicate question's answer: *`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` will return the 'permenant' path of the assembly.* Try that.

Comment: @KubaOber This also fails. The problem is Mono's implementation of mkbundle creating a temporary executable in the executing directory, so I'm not sure how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a mostly reliable method to find the path to `mkbundle` executables, however I'm not confident that this is the optimal solution.

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`